# Does creep always occur with load cells, or is there an optimum weight capacity?

Tags: sensor, measurement, load, load-cell

I want to make a scale which I will place under a wood stove (downdraft gasifier) to measure the amount of wood that goes into the wood stove. The amount of wood which is being measured will be displayed using a raspberry pi on a local page. After some research I was about to order four S-type load cells. The problem which I encountered was the permanent load placed on top of the load cells, which will result in 'creep' ([explanation of creep])[1](https://www.kiw.nl/file/1355354083.4482xeTAVU/11%20Loadcell%20accuracy.pdf). Most important quote from the link:

"The change in load cell output occurring with time while under constant load ( >90% of the load cell capacity ) and with all environmental conditions and other variables remaining constant."

The load cells are designed to measure weight for a short period of time. The load cells under the wood stove will be loaded with permanent weight. Does anyone know which load cells I could use to put permanently under the wood stove without loosing accuracy after long periods of time? Some technical information:

Wood stove itself weighs around 700 kg.

The capacity of wood in the stove is between 20 kg and 50 kg.

The desired accuracy is 0.5 ~ 1.0 kg. (0.1%, better accuracy would be great.)

The load cells won’t be (extremely) heated. The temperature will vary between 10 and 35°C, but that won’t be a problem I assume.

It is a little project on which I intent to spend a maximum amount of 200 euro’s on. Because it is quite some weight it would be the most steady if I use 4 load cells (each corner one load cell). All ideas are very welcome, even if the accuracy and/ or price won’t meet the desired conditions.

Comment: Why worry about creep?  Can't you zero (Tare) once in a while (when there's no load)?  ...and at the same time,  shunt-cal the output for continuous calibration checking.

Comment: That could work! Would creep occur the entire time? Say that I would tare it four times a year, for 5 years. Would the accuracy drop to a certain point that the displayed weight can't be trusted anymore? Or will the creep be reduced over a certain amount of time that it will be negligible?

Comment: I have a similar use case, and similar problem. Some work I've seen says creep is predictable and logarithmic over time.  If, big if, true, you could in theory compensate for it if you keep track of time since the load is applied.  However, in your application, as in my different application, the load will change over time, too.  If the load doesn't change "too fast", you might be able to simply compensate in the same way, but really, you can't, because your compensation would be a function of the load, and if the load changes, you don't know the load anymore and can't correctly compensate.